# Emulating ISO/IEC 15693 on Android

Tags: android, nfc, rfid, hce, iso-15693

Is it possible to emulate ISO/IEC 15693 cards on Android? According to my research Android currently supports read/write interaction with ISO/IEC 15693 cards, however I couldn't find any info on emulation. If the emulation is possible would it require secure element or/and HCE?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Android currently does not offer any API support for ISO 15693 host card emulation. Devices that support UICC-based card emulation over single wire protocol (+ HCI) might support proprietary(?) extensions to make the UICC emulate ISO 15693, but this is typically not the case either (note that this would be device manufacturer specific and beyond the scope of what AOSP currently provides).

Comment: thanks a lot for the answer! I've understood that there is no HCE support for ISO 15693 out of the box according to https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/hce.html#SupportedProtocols. But then why there is an NfcV class? What is it for?

Comment: you've mentioned that off-host card emulation is device manufacturer specific. Does it mean that if there is no such support then UICC based card emulation is also impossible? I couldn't find any relevant info regarding NXP or Broadcom chipsets. Given that UICC provides support for ISO 15693 I still depend on the NFC chipset characteristics, right?